# Are permissions granted by IMPORTRAGE bi-directional or one-way in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

If I want to import "Sheet A" from one workbook into "Sheet B" in another workbook by using `=IMPORTRANGE()` inside of Sheet B - when I grant it access to Sheet A is that permissions only 1 way? Meaning that If I add additional data to Sheet B will the users who have access to sheet A be able to see it? I assume not but wanted to verify.

Answer (score -1):

Users only have access to specific sheets (or "workbooks") as you grant it. If you give a user access to Sheet A (aka "Spreadsheet A" or "Workbook A"), they cannot access Sheet B (aka "Spreadsheet B" or "Workbook B") in any way unless you also grant that user access to the second spreadsheet. In fact, unless you tell someone, there is no way they would know in looking at or "fiddling with" one spreadsheet that you had even imported any data out to another spreadsheet.

Comment: The answer above isn't quite correct. Users with access to sheet A can sheet B if sheet A have been given permissions to use IMPORTRANGE. All they have to do is create an import range covering all the the data in sheet B.